# How to Display Coordinates on StatusStripLabel

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I want to Display Coordinates on StatusStripLabel when mousemove events rise
Blank Window is Form2 and StatusStriplabel is on Form1
When MouseMove Event on Form2 happened then Coordinates will Display on Form1 StatusStripLabel

Comment: Can you pass a reference of Form1 into Form2? That would make things easier for you.

Comment: yes i created reference of Form1 into Form2

Comment: You should be able to use that Form1 reference to access the StatusStripLabel.  Is that not working?  Could you post the code that is in your Form2_MouseMove event?